# SharpDX.Direct2D1.RenderTarget.EndDraw doesn't return HRESULT - how detect a failure? Especially D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET?

Tags: sharpdx

Porting code from Microsoft's old managed DirectX interfaces to SharpDX.

The documentation for [Microsoft's ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371924(v=vs.85).aspx) says that it should return an `HRESULT`:

> If the method succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code and sets tag1 and tag2 to the tags that were active when the error occurred.

Especially important is that this is the place I would usually detect the need to recreate the target (`D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET`). Indeed, Microsoft shows this in their example:

```
hr = m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
if (hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET) ...
```

SharpDX's implementation is a subroutine - no return value. As seen in [github source](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct2D1/RenderTarget.cs):

```
/// <returns>If the method succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code and sets tag1 and tag2 to the tags that were active when the error occurred. </returns>
    public void EndDraw()
```

The *comment* still mentions the HRESULT, but this is `void`-returning.

How do I see the HRESULT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining SharpDX source:

```
    public void EndDraw(out long tag1, out long tag2)
    {
        SharpDX.Result result = TryEndDraw(out tag1, out tag2);
        result.CheckError();
    }
```

which calls:

```
    public void CheckError()
    {
        if (_code < 0)
        {
            throw new SharpDXException(this);
        }
    }
```

The exception constructor:

```
    public SharpDXException(Result result)
        : this(ResultDescriptor.Find(result))
    {
        HResult = (int)result;
    }
```

Sets this field of SharpDXException:

```
public int HResult { get; protected set; }
```

Therefore, SharpDX exposes the HRESULT by throwing a `SharpDXException`, with the HRESULT readable as `ex.HResult`, if you have a `catch (SharpDXException ex)` clause.

---

More info:
[Convenience class to give names to the Direct2D exception HRESULTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46610926/199364).