# Python: Converting a numpy matrix to a grayscale image

Tags: numpy, image-processing

I want to convert a `numpy` matrix with **positive** and **negative** values of type `np.float` to a grayscale image with pixels from `[0,255]`. I want to do that as fast as possible.

Right now I am doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000
I = np.random.randn(n,n)
I_min = np.min(I)
I = I + np.abs(I_min)
I_max = np.max(I)
I = 255 * (I / I_max)
I = I.astype(np.uint8)
```

I hope that is correct!? Is there a faster way to do that? What can be improved?

Comment: Your code does not work when I_min is positive. I think `I = I + np.abs(I_min)` should be `I = I  - I_min`.

Comment: You want to multiply by 255.999 instead of 255, otherwise 255 will be underrepresented in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the smaller number of lines.

```
min_ = np.min(I)
max_ = np.max(I)
GI = (255 * (I-min_) / (max_-min_)).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: Nice! I did exactly the same but found it takes 485 microsec to do `np.min()` followed by `np.max()` as you did, but only 380 microsec to the `np.min()` on a separate thread in parallel while the main thread does `np.max()`. I didn't try splitting the final line of maths across multiple threads... yet!

Comment: @MarkSetchell is there no way of knowing ahead of time what your min and max are so you can skip that step entirely?

Comment: Does it make more sense to multiply by 255.9999 instead of 255 as suggested by @MarkRansom?

Comment: @Samuel It is up to you. This will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914115/converting-color-value-from-float-0-1-to-byte-0-255